# create timestamp links to jump to specific times on rumble videos

Tags: javascript, api, timestamp

I am trying to allow visitors to seek specific times on the embed rumble video inside the wordpress post by clicking to timestamp links. I can do it for youtube videos using Skip to Timestamp plugin or methods like [this one](https://wickydesign.com/how-to-add-timestamps-to-embedded-youtube-videos/) however, I cannot make it work for embed rumble videos.

I desperately need to make this work for a rumble video. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Although I appreciate user141080's attempt to give feedback on your question, he gave kind of a squirmy answer that did not address your concern.

I believe the question was how to create a timestamp link for a Rumble video. It did not ask about 3rd party software.

A hyperLink is a web browser function that takes an address as well as sometimes arguments to clarify a condition for a web server response, such as the video start time.

Best Answer: You can add:  ?start=xx (or &start=xx for additional parameter) to the end of the link, where xx = the number of seconds into the video to begin.

To start video at 33:22, first convert to seconds.
https://rumble.com/xxxMyVideo.html?start=2002 or
https://rumble.com/xxxMyVideo.html?pub=33x55&start=2002

There may be an easier way to insert mins, but I thought it up on the fly and Rumble is using seconds for start time.

Enjoy

Comment: This does work if you use the embed video code

Answer (score 0):

Setting the timestamps on a YouTube video works because YouTube allows it, this is not a functionality that Wordpress provides. For an rumble video you could use the [Rumble Player API](https://help.rumble.com/Rumble-Platform-API.html).

In the documentation there is the function "[API.setCurrentTime(time)](https://help.rumble.com/Player-Methods.html)" and it should do the same as in your linked example.